# Horizontal Multicols

Tags: multicolumn, alignment, tasks, horizontal

Since the answer for my last question [Tasks not accepting environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655322/tasks-not-accepting-environments) was pretty much: doesn't work, is there any alternative to tasks where the items are horizontally aligned?

Normal behavior of enumerate:
[image: normal enumerate]

Wanted:
[image: horizontal enumerate]

the possibility to enlarge items over multiple columns would be highly appreciated, but would do without, too.
What I don't want is to use tables.

Comment: Did you try to use the `enumerate*` environment from package `enumitem`?

Comment: Ah, writing questions on a small screen didn't let me see that my formatting looked like an inline enumeration. Edited the question to fit my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to simulate `tasks` from your other question, which might work with `versions`. For instance, I defined a new counter. Then, used that with `paracol` with a custom list. `paracol` can particularly be useful because it splits a part of a document into columns and continues each column that is longer then available space.

In the example below, the counter is set to numbers in format `(1)`, `(2)` etc. If you change `\arabic{myenum}` to `\alph{myenum}`, it will show letters, instead (see [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Counters) for other available formats).

Finally, this example compiles with `versions` and hopefully can work with this package.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{versions}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\newcounter{myenum}
\renewcommand{\themyenum}{(\alph{myenum})}
\globalcounter{myenum}
\newcommand\myenum[1]{%
  \stepcounter{myenum}%
  \begin{list}{}{
      \setlength\labelwidth{1.5em}
      \setlength\labelsep{0.5em}
      \setlength\listparindent{15pt}
      \setlength\leftmargin{2em}
      \setlength\parsep{0pt}
    }\item[\themyenum]#1
  \end{list}}
\newcommand\myenumplain{\stepcounter{myenum}\themyenum\hspace{0.5em}}


\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
  \myenum{\kant[1-2]}
\switchcolumn
  \myenum{\kant[3]}
\end{paracol}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \myenum{\kant[4]}
  \switchcolumn
  \myenum{\kant[5-6]}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```